# Помогите, найти ошибку в коде, метод replaceFirst

Tags: java, строки, append

помогите, пожалуйста, найти баг в коде. У меня есть 2 массива: массив ролей и массив строк в сценарии. Мне необходимо, чтобы код выводил пронумерованные строки в порядке ролей.

Пример ввода 1:

```
roles:

Городничий
Аммос Федорович
Артемий Филиппович
Лука Лукич

textLines:

Городничий: Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.
Аммос Федорович: Как ревизор?
Артемий Филиппович: Как ревизор?
Городничий: Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.
Аммос Федорович: Вот те на!
Артемий Филиппович: Вот не было заботы, так подай!
Лука Лукич: Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!
```

Пример вывода 1:

```
Городничий:
1) Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.
4) Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.

Аммос Федорович:
2) Как ревизор?
5) Вот те на!

Артемий Филиппович:
3) Как ревизор?
6) Вот не было заботы, так подай!

Лука Лукич:
7) Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!
```

У меня код работает неправильно, он выводит роли и подряд пронумерованные строки для каждой роли от 1) до 8). Не могу понять где ошибка.

Второй вопрос: Как правильнее писать

```
result.append(roles[i]).append(":\n");
```

или

```
result.append(roles[i] + ":" + '\n');
```

заранее большое спасибо за помощь :)
Мой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] roles = new String[]{
            "Городничий",
            "Аммос Федорович",
            "Артемий Филиппович",
            "Лука",
            "Лука Лукич"
    };
    String[] textLines = new String[]{
            "Городничий: Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.",
            "Аммос Федорович: Как ревизор?",
            "Артемий Филиппович: Как ревизор?",
            "Городничий: Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.",
            "Аммос Федорович: Вот те на!",
            "Артемий Филиппович: Вот не было заботы, так подай!",
            "Лука Лукич: Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!",
            "Лука: Господи боже! Я уронил своё пасхальное яйцо от неожиданности!"
    };
    System.out.println(printTextPerRole(new String[]{"Городничий", "Аммос Федорович", "Артемий Филиппович", "Лука", "Лука Лукич"},
            new String[]{"Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор.", "Как ревизор?",
                    "Как ревизор?", "Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем.", "Вот те на!", "Вот не было заботы, так подай!",
                    "Господи боже! еще и с секретным предписаньем!", "Господи боже! Я уронил своё пасхальное яйцо от неожиданности!"}));

}

public static String printTextPerRole(String[] roles, String[] textLines) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        result.append(roles[i] + ":" + '\n');

        for (int j = 0; j < textLines.length; j++) {
            if (textLines[j].startsWith(roles[i] + ":")) {


        result.append((textLines[j].replaceFirst(roles[i] + ":", j + 1 + ")")) + "\n");
            }
            result.append('\n');
             }
            }
             return result.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(printTextPerRole(roles, textLines));
```

> ... и подряд пронумерованные строки для каждой роли от 1) до 8).

Что-то я не вижу, как это может быть.

> Второй вопрос: Как правильнее писать

Это не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: не работает. Внесу уточнения: Метод printTextPerRole должен группировать строчки по ролям, пронумеровывать их и возвращать результат в виде готового текста (см. пример). Каждая группа распечатывается в следующем виде:

Роль:
i) текст 
j) текст2
...
==перевод строки==

i и j -- номера строк в сценарии. Индексация строчек начинается с единицы, выводить группы следует в соответствии с порядком ролей. Переводы строк между группами обязательны, переводы строк в конце текста не учитываются. в качестве перевода строки надо использовать символ '\n' (перевод строки в стиле UNIX);

Comment: @user4166 "не работает." - ??

Comment: Igor, прошу прощения, туплю. Правильно я понимаю, что нужно вместо моих строк кода: result.append('\n');
             }
            }
             return result.toString();    написать       System.out.println(printTextPerRole(roles, textLines));

Comment: @user4166 Нет. Tам, где у Вас строчка `System.out.println(printTextPerRole(new String[]{"Городничий", "Аммос Федорович",...`, напишите строчку из ответа.

Comment: Igor, большое спасибо за помощь! Сразу не заметила )